# How to send 10-20KiB with UDP semantics?

Tags: udp, packet-loss, fragmentation

I have volatile traffic, of 10-20KiB, that I want to send with UDP semantics.

I have measured packet loss between several servers across the internet.  In testing, I can reliably get 32KiB UDP packets between wired servers.

Between a server on the internet and a mobile app, significant packet loss starts at just 2KiB.

- Are 32KiB UDP packets generally reliable across the internet, between wired servers?
- If not, are a series of numbered X byte packets the best alternative?
- What size is X?  (Reading about DNS makes me think that it's ~500 bytes.)

Comment: UDP datagrams are recommended to be small (~576 byte) because UDP is unreliable, and you _will_ lose datagrams. The bigger the datagram, the more data you lose when one is lost. In any case, IP packets larger than the path MTU must be fragmented, which slows packet forwarding, and the loss of a single fragment will cause the entire IP pack to be discarded. Many businesses simply drop packet fragments because of fragmentation attacvks.

Comment: UDP datagrams larger than the path MTU (anywhere between 576 and 1500 bytes minus 28 bytes overhead) require fragmentation, increasing packet loss and decreasing likelihood of forwarding. You should either probe the path MTU and make your application protocol capable of sending multiple UDP datagrams, or consider TCP.